# use get methods in telegram

Tags: symfony, telegram

I want to get the response of getChat method in symfony for telegram but how use it?
https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/getChat?chat_id=@channelName
this is the response in postman:

```
{
"ok": true,
"result": {
    "id": -1001000737610,
    "title": "کانال  ",
    "username": "gizmiztel",
    "type": "channel",
    "description": "ارسال سوژه @alogizmiz\n\nتبلیغات @gizmiz_ad\n\nاینستاگرام instagram.com/_u/gizmiztel\n\nسایت gizmiz.com",
    "photo": {
        "small_file_id": "AQADBAATOIVnGQAElEEaamARX9hoWgIAAQI",
        "big_file_id": "AQADBAATOIVnGQAE21YqJKH-YwZqWgIAAQI"
    }
}
}
```

for send message I use this kind but for get i don't know what to do:

```
  $result = [
            'method' => 'sendMessage',
            'chat_id' => $chatId,
            'text' => 'خطای سرور'
        ];
return new JsonResponse($result, Response::HTTP_OK);
```

Comment: have you tried changing 'method' field to 'getChat' and removing the 'text' field in $result ?

Comment: yeah but I get the response in postman ,I want it in my code for processing

Comment: sorry i don't get what do you mean by postman maybe i haven't heard of.
or do you mean in json ? do you need to convert the json response to variables so you can use it in your code ?

Comment: It is a software,the main problem is I don't know how write codes to get the response,I don't have any problems with json

Comment: check the api doc it may help you find the answer.
http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html
maybe its some method like getContent or etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) or [PHP Curl](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for get result from any HTTP client.

For using guzzle http client:

> Reqire "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "version" in your package.json and run composer update command.

Then you can use it like this:

```
    <?php

    namespace Foo\BarBundle\Driver;

    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    class GetResultFromTelegram
    {
        protected client;

        public function getInfoOfChannel() 
        {
            $baseUrl = 'https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/getChatchat_id=@channelName';
            $this->client = new Client();

            $res = $this->client->request('GET', $baseUrl);
            // Convert response to array.
            return json_decode($res->getBody(), true);
        }
    }
```